# Unable to Send Data to Javascript via Templates Bottle

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2, bottle

I have a small Python script which is supposed to send a string to the javascript in my HTML file to be rendered on the page. However, the script is not receiving the data sent to it from the Python file. My code is below:

simple.html:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <p1 id="demo"></p1>
   <script>
    var s  = {{to_display}};
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = s;
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

main.py:

```
from bottle import Bottle, template

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def index():
   data = {"to_display":"HI, how are you"}
   return template("simple.html", data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I would like the page to look like this:

```
Hello

HI, how are you
```

Unfortunately, it is only displaying:

```
Hello
```

Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the template is not rendering valid javascript.

```
>>> from bottle import template
>>> data = {'to_display': 'HI, how are you'}
>>> rendered = template('/home/kev/tmp/test.html', data)
>>> print rendered
<html>
  <body>
    <p1 id="demo"></p1>
    <script>
        var s = HI, how are you;
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        x.innerHTML = s;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Loading this html in the browser raises a syntax error (tested on Firefox 52.3.0):

`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

The problem is that the definition of `s` is not quoted within the `<script>` tag.  Fixed version:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p1 id="demo"></p1>
    <script>
        var s = "{{ to_display }}";
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        x.innerHTML = s;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Renders to this markup, which works as expected in the browser:

```
>>> print rendered
<html>
  <body>
    <p1 id="demo"></p1>
    <script>
        var s = "HI, how are you";
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        x.innerHTML = s;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```